# How to change time zone from GMT to PST in DocuSign for Audit Trails?

Tags: java, docusignapi

I've been trying to change the time zone from GMT to PST in DocuSign while retrieving the Audit Trails. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: *PST isn't a time zone*. It's either an abbreviation for an offset which the `America/Los_Angeles` timezone uses for part of the year, or it refers to the `Asia/Manila` time zone.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any idea on conversion?

Comment: What do you mean by Audit Trails?  How are you retrieving the the Audit Trails?

Comment: Through REST calls. It's a series of events in DocuSign.

Comment: Can you please let us know the exact REST call you are using.

Comment: @CodingDawg -- probably https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents/

Answer (score 1):

Goto Classic admin. See the item "Timezone for the API"

[image]